# Add additional fields to the list of permitted ones in an devise Invitation controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've some additional fields to the "accept inviation form" and I need to permit them in a controller. I did this according to the documentation:

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  private

  def accept_resource
    resource_class.accept_invitation!(update_resource_params)
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters

    # error here
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation).concat [:field1, :field2, :field3]

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:accept_invitation) do |u|
      u.permit(:field1, :field2, :field3, :password, :password_confirmation, :invitation_token)
    end
  end
```

I need to allow ":field1, :field2, :field3". Am I doing it right? I have an error

```
undefined method `for' for #<Devise::ParameterSanitizer:0x007f20fe0d5220> Did you mean? fork
```

Comment: What version of `Devise` do you use?

Comment: devise_invitable (1.6.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method `for` was [deprecated and successfully removed](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FParameterSanitizer%3Afor) from `Devise`.

Use [`permit`/`sanitize`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/ParameterSanitizer) instead, or downgrade to 4.0 (not recommended).

Comment: я так и знал давно, что ты русский. вот жук.

Comment: Кто жук? Я никогда этого и не скрывал.